# Expand height of div to reach bottom of container from it's initial position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a basic HTML page set up with a container with content and a child element at the bottom with no set height like this:

```
<div id="parent">
      ^
      |
      |    //other elements here of variable height depending on content output
      | 
      |
      v
   <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

Now the `parent` has a size of lets say `500px` in `height`.

What i want to do, is to get the current position of `child` (which currently has not got a set height) relative to the container, and then calculate the height needed to expand the child to the bottom of the parent.

The issue is how do i get the current position for `top:` of `child` relative to parent? That way I can calculate how much height is required to reach the bottom of the parent and then use `myEl.style.height = height+'px';`

I don't know if this matters but i am not using position absolute/relative. I am using default display.

**Side note:**

I would welcome a pure `CSS` solution `if` it is more elegant and not hacky compared to `JS`, but i could not find a CSS property to do this.

Comment: #parent {position:relative;} #child {position:absolute;bottom:0px;} ..did work? :)

Comment: @yjs No because the height of child would still be zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal flow: i think this is what you mean. i'm sorry i do not understand your question very well.

N:

> a block-level element height is, if not set, designed to fit hes children

so `.child` height is 100% (he fit it's content) `.parent` height is 100% (he fit it's content) so is no height is set to `.parent` the `.child` will always hit bottom. If `.parent` height is set greater than 100% (5000px example) you need to position both `.child` (absolute to hit bottom) & `.parent` (relative, to be an position ancestor).

```css
div.spaceTruck {
  outline: 1px solid green;
  background-color: lime;
}
div.spaceTruck > span {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}
div.spaceTruck > div {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="spaceTruck">
  <span>Dark content</span>
  <span>Dark content</span>
  <span>Dark content</span>
  <span>Dark content</span>
  <span>Dark content</span>
  <span>Dark content</span>
  <span>Dark content</span>
  <span>Dark content</span>
  <span>Dark content</span>
  <span>Dark content</span>
  <div>
    spaceeeetruckking!!!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is position going to adjust the height of my element ?

Comment: ooo, now i read the comment carefull i see what you trying to reach..  a min please :)

Comment: Also please don't edit my question to remove tags that i actually want.

Comment: Your initial question did look as a CSS question, i'm sorry many people did not understand you.. we are here to help.. better tags on question will make people better check your question out.

Comment: I welcome either Javascript or a CSS solution - which ever is most elegant.

Comment: @yjs you know that way is it set to 100% meaning if will overflow the parent.

Comment: @PhilAndelhofs plus my parent element does not have a set height, it varies as it depends on the content inside of it. Thats why i think javascript is the solution most likely.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {
     height:100%;
    }

    #parent {
      position:relative;
      height:auto;
      }

    #child {
      position:relative;
      height:100%;
      background:#ccc;
      }
```

```html
<div id="parent">Parent div
          <p>► fix grammatical or spelling errors

       ► clarify meaning without changing it

       ► correct minor mistakes

       ► add related resources or links

       ► always respect the original author</p>
          <p>► fix grammatical or spelling errors

       ► clarify meaning without changing it

       ► correct minor mistakes

       ► add related resources or links

       ► always respect the original author</p>
          <p>► fix grammatical or spelling errors

       ► clarify meaning without changing it

       ► correct minor mistakes

       ► add related resources or links

       ► always respect the original author</p>
          <p>► fix grammatical or spelling errors

       ► clarify meaning without changing it

       ► correct minor mistakes

       ► add related resources or links

       ► always respect the original author</p>
       <div id="child">Child div - Some text</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Again as i already said in the initial comments, this is not useful i don't want the element at the bottom of the div, i want it to expand from where it is to the bottom of the parent div.

Comment: My parent element does not have a set height, it varies as it depends on the content inside of it.

Comment: @Dave you can set height of #parent { height:auto; } updated code...above!

Comment: Pretty sure that is default anyway?

Comment: yep! you can try content with yours... :)